# OnClick form button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a onclick event to a submit button of a dynamicaly generated form, and the simplified version of form looks like this:

```
<div class="form">
   <form action="demo_form.php">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-submit">
  </form>  
</div>
```

I was wondering is this the right way to add it (i am a javascript newbie), aka is the code formated correctly

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.form .wpcf7-submit').onclick = ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact Form', eventAction: 'Submit', eventLabel: 'Send Contact', eventValue: 50});;
```

Comment: Why did you tag jQuery?

Comment: just to see does somebody have a better jquery alternative to what i wrote above :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.wpcf7-submit')[0].onclick = function() {
    ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact Form', eventAction: 'Submit', eventLabel: 'Send Contact', eventValue: 50});;
}
```

Comment: If i may, one question :) Would there be easier way to just append this onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact Form', eventAction: 'Send Contact', eventLabel: 'Send', eventValue: 50});" to a submit button?

Comment: No, you can't use ga(...) not wrapped to additional function because in this way ga will be called immediatelly instead of on click event. Also it is bad practice to use html on- attributes.

Comment: ahhh, okay, i think i understand, thank you! if you dont mind, could you take a look at this and advise would it work https://jsfiddle.net/ctm2chnj/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add event via codding you can use **.addEventListener()**
method of javascript which will append event.

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".form .wpcf7-submit'")[0].addEventListner("click",YourFunctionName);
```

Extra Info:-
Here [0] is an index of that element you can specify whatever element you want to fetch. Moreover index always starts from 0. Real Time Example:-

```
<p class="Test"></p>
<p class="Test"></p>

document.getElementsByClassName("Test")[0].addEventListner("click",Fade);
```

This will fetch element at 0 or first `<p>` tag

Answer (score 0):

As others have already noted, you could do something like this on the frontend:

```
document.querySelector('.wpcf7-submit').onclick = function() {
    ga('send', 'event', { 
                            eventCategory: 'Contact Form', 
                            eventAction: 'Submit', 
                            eventLabel: 'Send Contact', 
                            eventValue: 50
                        });
}
```

However, judgint by the HTML provided, you're using Contact Form 7, which has built-in solutions for this so you don't have to pollute your frontend with tracking code if you have access to the admin interface of your WP install.

Simply add the following to the 'additional settings' section of your WPCF7 settings page:

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact Form', eventAction: 'Submit', eventLabel: 'Send Contact', eventValue: 50});"
```

I like to keep my contact form related functionality in one place, but that's up to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jQuery, Here is a jQuery alternative demo:

```js
// adding an on click event on the form's submit button
$('.form .wpcf7-submit').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); // NOTE: comment this out to let the form execute demo_form.php 
    
    // call ga() function with the necessary parameters
    ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact Form', eventAction: 'Submit', eventLabel: 'Send Contact', eventValue: 50});
    
})

function ga(eventname, purpose, formObject) {
 console.log(eventname);
    console.log(purpose);
    console.log(formObject);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
   <form action="demo_form.php">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-submit">
  </form>  
</div>
```